# Dockerfile Works Locally But Fails on EB (Elastic Beanstalk) Deploy (PHP 7.3 with OCI8 extension)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oracle, amazon-ebs, oracle10g

Good day, fellow developers!

I have been searching for 2 weeks now on how to install the `OCI8 PHP extension` on Elastic Beanstalk using `.ebextensions` but sadly I can't search for similar ones.

Before I arrived at the conclusion to use `.ebextensions`, I tried the Docker approach first. I created an image with **OCI8 PHP extension** and **Oracle Instant Client** dependencies. It was working fine on my local Docker Hub app but errors appeared when I tried deploying it to EB.

After reading some more information, I stumbled upon this AWS article: [How do I install PECL 7 modules on Elastic Beanstalk environments running on PHP with Amazon Linux 1 stacks?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-pecl7-modules-php/). From that, I concluded that this is the best option in my case. The problem now is there are almost no articles that can be found which pertain to OCI8, Elastic Beanstalk, and `.ebextensions`.

Has anyone tried using the `.ebextensions` config files to install the **OCI8 PHP extension**?
Any clue will really help.

Answer (score 0):

We have been able to install oci8 and oracle client using .ebextensions. We created 2 config files, one for the oracle stuff:

```
commands:
  01_install_basic:
     command: |
            cd /tmp
            wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/oracle-instantclient-basic-linuxx64.rpm
            rpm -i oracle-instantclient-basic-linuxx64.rpm
     test: '! rpm -qa |grep oracle-instantclient-basic'
  02_install_devel:
    command: |
            cd /tmp
            wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/oracle-instantclient-devel-linuxx64.rpm
            rpm -i oracle-instantclient-devel-linuxx64.rpm
    test: '! rpm -qa |grep oracle-instantclient-devel'
  03_install_sqlplus:
    command: |
            cd /tmp
            wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-linuxx64.rpm
            rpm -i oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-linuxx64.rpm
            export CLIENT_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64
            export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CLIENT_HOME/lib
            export PATH=$PATH:$CLIENT_HOME/bin
    test: '! rpm -qa |grep oracle-instantclient-sqlplus'
```

And the second for the oci8 module

```
commands:
  02_install_oci8:
    command:  echo '' | /usr/bin/pecl install oci8-2.2.0
    test: '! php -m |grep oci8'
```

It's probably not perfect but it's work for us!

Regards,

Eric